# FCM Push Notifications are not working through REST but works from FCM console

Tags: json, curl, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

My curl request is as follows:

```
curl -i -H "Authorization: key=YOUR_KEY" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @nt.json https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

content of nt.json:

```
{"to":"fS8pdgESa5A:APA91bHt8MO6_byOvVqC__721JnazpdvHx2XxJSP3_xC5BN2Lxhd0ZV91ozAxTCa3lW2kIRObkVlNmEFuz9OlHW1WA_NB6_6WEIWL0L5NiDiuxkFuXP6qpazjyfR2DMkQJ3Zu1B5t0uq","notification":{"title":"hi4","body":"hi4body"}}
```

Comment: Could you add the response you get after sending your curl request?

Comment: @ArthurThompson  {"multicast_id":8733896297738094821,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1465371113456675%9b307614f9fd7ecd"}]}

Comment: Could you try adding a priority: High to the payload in your nt.json field?

Comment: Yeah It worked. Thank you @ArthurThompson